# node . is not working and my bot will not go online. Instead I get the error code code: 'ClientMissingIntents'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im following a tutorial because im new to this.

**CODE**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '';

const prefix = '';

bot.on('ready', () => {

    console.log('I Am Online')

})

bot.login(token)
```

The only thing that is different when running "Node ." is the toekn is in place.

**Error Code**

code: 'ClientMissingIntents'

What am I doing wrong? I have Node.js installed. Followed everything step byt step, his worked but mine didnt.

Comment: Please do a thorough search for the error message before posting a new question here. Google indexes SO posts very well, so a basic Google search will help you find any existing questions about the topic. We expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself before posting here, and part of that effort is to perform extensive searches first.

Comment: Okay firstly I did search, I am new idk what to look for for the most part. I hate posting here cause I didnt wanna be judged. I only posted cause I honestly couldnt figure it out, but thanks for your opinion dude.

Comment: _"but thanks for your opinion dude"_ That's a great way to ask for help...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using v12 or v13 code on discord.js v14. Your first error was that you included `Discord` as the entire node module. This isn't really an error but it's better to now import `{ Client }` instead of `Discord` This would make your code look like this now:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
```

Then, in order to initiate the client with this you would create a new Client.  But your real mistake is that you didn't initiate it with GatewayIntents. In the spot where you're initiating your client, you need to add the intents.

Also, I noticed that you created a prefix variable. Since your issues appear they are coming from v14, it's best you don't use prefix command and instead use slash commands.

This would make your code look like this after all the edits:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const token = '';

bot.on('ready', () => {

    console.log('I Am Online')

})

client.login(token)
```